# @RestController With Synchronization

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

This is just for understanding as the below code didn't give the expected result. So wanted to know if there is anything I am missing.

```
@RestController
public class TestRestController {

    @GetMapping("/helloworld/{parm}")
    public synchronized void helloWorld(@PathVariable("parm") String data) throws Exception{

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" helloworld ....Start"+new Date() +"  "+ data);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" helloworld ....End"+ new Date());

    }

    @GetMapping("/hello/{parm}")
    public synchronized void hello(@PathVariable("parm") String data) throws Exception{

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" hello ....Start"+new Date() +"  "+ data);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" hello ....End"+ new Date());

    }
}
```

Executing these end-points in the below sequence.

```
http://localhost:8080/hello/4
http://localhost:8080/helloworld/3
```

Actual output

```
http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:37 IST 2023  4
http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....EndWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023
http-nio-8080-exec-2 helloworld ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023  3
http-nio-8080-exec-2 helloworld ....EndWed Sep 13 21:23:52 IST 2023
```

Expecting output(Don't consider the timestamp. copypaste from the above)

```
http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:37 IST 2023  4
http-nio-8080-exec-2 helloworld ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023  3
http-nio-8080-exec-2 helloworld ....EndWed Sep 13 21:23:52 IST 2023
http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....EndWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023
```

My understanding is that Restcontroller is singleton and methods are non-thread safe in general. Now after adding synchronization only that method gets locked after getting the request the other method shouldn't locked and executed immediately when another request hits that endpoint.

Comment: If you will change `synchronized` to `ReentrantLock` class that implements the `Lock` interface all will work as expected. Can you try it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Actual Output is correct ,and the expectation is not correct.

if you see the actual output's first two lines

> ```
> http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:37 IST 2023  4
> http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....EndWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023
> ```

The first Thread of your app http-nio-8080-exec-1 got the lock and 2nd thread http-nio-8080-exec-2 was waiting until the 1st thread finished , since it is waiting outside for the lock it will not print anything

> http-nio-8080-exec-2 helloworld ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023
> 3

immediate and the 2nd method will wait until 1st releases the lock.

**so the flow will be**

```
http://localhost:8080/hello/4 --> at Sep 13 21:23:37 IST 2023
call reaches public synchronized void hello()
Lock aquired
```

printed

```
http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....StartWed Sep 13 21:23:37 IST 2023  4
Assuming some where here you made the 2nd call
```

http://localhost:8080/helloworld/3

public synchronized void helloWorld() --> will attempt to accquire lock but will wait for 1st method because it would be in Thread.sleep()

**2nd thread will wait until thread sleep() finish for the hello method()/1st Thread**

```
then 1st method will print 
http-nio-8080-exec-1 hello ....EndWed Sep 13 21:23:47 IST 2023
```

> ```
> Then only Lock will be release as method will exit then. and 2nd thread will be executed
> ```

Comment: Ok. If I understood correctly if I create multiple instances of Rest Controller in that case it can produce the expected output and synchronization + singleton instance provide the same behaviors as it is class-level synchronization.